# why ss(8) understands listening UDP ports differently than netstat(8)?

Tags: udp, netstat

If I execute `ss -lu` in order to view all the listening UDP sockets, then none of the sockets are displayed. If I execute `ss -au`, which lists all(both listening and non-listening) UDP sockets, then "listening" sockets are displayed as UNCONN (see below).

What is the logic behind this? For example running **atftpd** listening for connections, should have state LISTEN not UNCONN, shouldn't it?

```
T60:~ # lsof -n | sed -n '1p;/UDP/p'
  COMMAND    PID TID  USER    FD  TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
avahi-dae    963     avahi   11u  IPv4    9088      0t0   UDP *:mdns
avahi-dae    963     avahi   12u  IPv4    9089      0t0   UDP *:44639
    cupsd   1238      root   10u  IPv4    8160      0t0   UDP *:ipp
   dhcpcd   2072      root    7u  IPv4  532052      0t0   UDP *:bootpc
dhclient6  13131      root    5u  IPv6   38031      0t0   UDP *:dhcpv6-client
dhclient6  13131      root   20u  IPv4   37954      0t0   UDP *:20152
dhclient6  13131      root   21u  IPv6   37955      0t0   UDP *:36745
   atftpd  20639      tftp    0u  IPv4  344977      0t0   UDP *:tftp
```

netstat

```
T60:~ # netstat -lu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                 
udp        0      0 *:tftp                  *:*                                 
udp        0      0 *:44639                 *:*                                 
udp        0      0 *:ipp                   *:*                                 
udp        0      0 *:20152                 *:*                                 
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*                                 
udp        0      0 *:36745                 *:*                                 
udp        0      0 *:dhcpv6-client         *:*
```

ss

```
T60:~ # ss -lu
Recv-Q Send-Q   Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port

T60:~ # ss -ua
State       Recv-Q Send-Q   Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port
UNCONN      0      0                    *:bootpc                     *:*
UNCONN      0      0                    *:tftp                       *:*
UNCONN      0      0                    *:44639                      *:*
UNCONN      0      0                    *:ipp                        *:*
UNCONN      0      0                    *:20152                      *:*
UNCONN      0      0                    *:mdns                       *:*
UNCONN      0      0                   :::36745                     :::*
UNCONN      0      0                   :::dhcpv6-client             :::*


T60:~ # ss -v
ss utility, iproute2-ss110629
```

Comment: Maybe just wording? A listening socket is obviously unconnected... ;-)

Comment: @HaukeLaging Not to mention both sound bad considering UDP :)

Comment: I've noticed that the behavior of `-ul` varies between RHEL5 and RHEL6. It is meaningless to RHEL5, but RHEL6 does what you'd expect it to. (the state is still listed as `UNCONN` in the output, but it only shows the listeners)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UDP is a connectionless protocol.  SS probably won't show one in LISTEN state, only in UCONN or ESTAB.

If I do this,

```
$ nc -u -l 2333
```

Then ss will show (in a 2nd shell):

```
$ ss -au|grep 2333
UNCONN     0      0                       *:2333                     *:*
```

If I then connect to it (3rd shell)

```
$ nc -u localhost 2333
```

then SS shows:

```
$ ss -au|grep 2333
ESTAB      0      0               127.0.0.1:2333             127.0.0.1:58434   
ESTAB      0      0               127.0.0.1:58434            127.0.0.1:2333
```