# How to check which localhost's ports are used on the terminal?

Tags: linux, networking, port

I'm working on the Linux Ubuntu terminal and I'm wondering how to check directly on terminal which localhost ports are used please ?

Comment: "used" in what way? something's listening there for incoming connections? Or there's a connection using that port?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why ss(8) understands listening UDP ports differently than netstat(8)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72748/why-ss8-understands-listening-udp-ports-differently-than-netstat8)

Answer (score 8):

You can use use the `ss` command.

```
$ ss -natu
```

The `n` option means don't translate addresses to names.  The `a` options means show all (listening and non-listening) connections.  The `t` option means TCP connections.  The 'u' option means show UDP connections.

Note that `ss` might not be in your path by default.  For example, you might need to run `/sbin/ss`.

Comment: thanks for your answer Andy Dalton, I have found more easily the port I sought for using "sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN ", what do you think about that?

Comment: That's legit too

Answer (score 3):

There's `netstat` for this. Try:

```
netstat -apv
```

Or better:

```
sudo netstat -apv
```

`sudo`, becuase some entries may be masked for security reasons. `a` for all. `p` for program names. `v` for more verbose output.

Comment: Netstat is deprecated on Debian. Use `ss` instead...

Comment: @Fabby I'm still with the old, though I've heard about `ss`. Is Netstat really as much as deprecated? Can you post a link to this?

Comment: `man netstat` under Debian.

Comment: @Fabby I've got it in the NOTES: *This program is mostly obsolete. (...)* Cheers.